What are the symbols used in First Folio of Coriolanus? ("A?tus Primus" / "?with")
In the image below, taken from https://firstfolio.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/text/619 there are two symbols that made me curious.
The first symbol is obviously "c" but is it just a stylized "c" or some specific type of "c"? Or maybe the stylization has a distinct name?
The second symbol looks like a misprint, but it probably isn't.


Does this answer your question? What is the symbol connecting the letters "c" and "t" called, and when did it go out of style?

What makes you think that the ‘ﬁrst symbol is obviously “c,” ’ there? Are you saying that some comma or cedille following the letter C got floated up to the top of the base letter instead of staying put at the bottom like with ⟨ꝣ⟩, the Visigothic Zet?

@Laurel Yes, if the second symbol is just a dab and the first is a ct-ligature, that completely answers my question. Many thanks!

@tchrist I'm not very familiar with typographical terminology, so what I meant is that it's c because the whole word is Actus.

@tchrist Also, that was my typo. I edited the question; sorry about that. There's no c, here.

@user619271 Oh I see. Thank you very much.

This question is similar to: What is the symbol connecting the letters "c" and "t" called, and when did it go out of style?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I voted to close the question as a duplicate of the question that Laurel cites in her first comment above. However, two other close voters (besides me) voted to close it as needing to be more focused—so that's the specified close reason, although I do not endorse that reason. The second mark that the poster asks about is not a typographical character, as far as I can tell, but simply an ink smear.
